# jinja2's way of stripping all alphanumeric and special characters?

Tags: python, xslt, jinja2

Trying to strip all of the special and alphanumberic characters from a string in jinja2.

XSLT:

```
  <xsl:variable name="splChar">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$&amp;%^*()_+.[]{}|\~`:;",'.?&lt;&gt;=
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($str,$splChar,'')" />
```

jinja2:

```
  {% str | replace("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$&amp;%^*()_+.[]{}|\~`:;",'.?", "")  %}
```

Comment: Is custom filter an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately the platform that I am working on you cannot implement a custom filter, I should have mentioned that

Comment: So, this is not about XSLT. You are just ussing the language as example.

Comment: Sure, but I am translating from xslt to jinja2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with `regex_replace`.

It replaces all charactars that are not (`^`) alphanumeric (`A-Za-z0-9`) by nothing (`""`):

```
{% test_string | regex_replace ("[^A-Za-z0-9]","") %}
```

With the following `test_string`: `'AAA\B\©©c\\oTT$e#Teste00-4?'`, 
it returns `AAABcoTTeTeste004` as expected!

Comment: Are you sure we have `regex_replace` function available in Jinja?

Comment: You're right. It seems that `regex_replace` is an Ansible filter!